# Ionic 2: "black screen" after modal close

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a Modal page:

```
import {Page, ViewController, NavParams} from 'ionic-framework/ionic';
@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/tosmodal/tosmodal.html'
})
export class TOSModal {

    static get parameters() {
        return [[NavParams], [ViewController]];
    }

    constructor(navParams, viewCtrl) {
        this.data = navParams.data;
        this.viewCtrl = viewCtrl;
    }

    close() {
        this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
    }
}
```

when the close() is called, the modal is dismissed but the previous page doesn't appear. To the `<ion-page>` element, a display:none is added:

```
ion-page {
    display: none;
}
```

Am I missing something? Maybe in the onDismiss method?

Answer (score 3):

Don't understand really why, but when opening the modal, if it's presentend inside a setTimeout(), then the close works as expected:

```
setTimeout( () => {
    this.nav.present(modal);
})
```